# Adding business logic on components in the ui.qml files

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick-designer

I have a QML Quick Form where I have an image and an associated mouse area as follows:

```
// StatusBarForm.ui.qml
Image {
    id: exitButton
    width: 24
    height: 24
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: 5
    source: "images/exit.png"

    MouseArea {
        id: exitButtonMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Now, according to the docs I should separate the business logic and the designer created a `StatusBar.qml` form and I added:

```
exitButtonMouseArea.onClicked: {
    Qt.quit()
}
```

Now the thing is I tested it with Qt 5.9 on a mac and it worked (although the Qt creator highlighted the `onClicked` handler complaining that `exitButtonMouseArea identifier was not valid`. I also tried `exitButton.exitButtonMouseArea.onClicked:`

Now I tried it with `Qt 5.8` on Linux and the application does not initialize. if I remove the event handler it's fine except of course I cannot interact with the image.

So, my question is how can I provide the business logic outside of the UI file in my case.

**EDIT**
Following @derM answer, I did the following:

```
// StatusBarForm.ui.qml
Image {
    id: exitButton
    width: 24
    height: 24
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: 5
    source: "images/exit.png"    
}

// StatusBar.qml
StatusBarForm {
    property alias exitButton: exitButton

    Image {
        id: exitButton
        MouseArea {
            id: exitButtonMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                Qt.quit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While my component initializes, I never get the `onClicked` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you can access objects by their `id` only within the same file or crawling up in the object tree.

If you read [**this**](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html#using-qt-quick-ui-forms) carefully, you will find, that they don't access the button by it's `id`, but they *export the button as a property*

This is done by this line:

```
property alias button: button
```

Once exported, you can access it from the outside by using the property name.

---

*From the documentation:*

> The property alias exports the button to the QML code that uses the form. **You can use the  (Export) button in the Navigator to export an item as a property**:
> [image: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html#using-qt-quick-ui-forms]
> <sub>(source: [doc.qt.io](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/images/qmldesigner-export-item.png))</sub>

---

In your code this would look like this:

// StatusBarForm.ui.qml

```
Image {
    id: exitButton
    width: 24
    height: 24
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: 5
    source: "images/exit.png"

    // export the MouseArea as a property here
    property alias exitButtonMouseArea: exitButtonMouseArea

    MouseArea {
        id: exitButtonMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

//main.qml

```
StatusBarExitForm {
    // access the MouseArea via the property here
    exitButtonMouseArea.onClicked: Qt.quit()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my edit. I am not sure what I have missed. The issue is that the event I am trying is on a MouseArea of the Image object.

Comment: I think in your edit, you messed it up some more. You can/should add the `MouseArea` in the form. You export it in the form as a property. When you instantiate/use the form, you can handle the signal by accessing the `MouseArea` through the affore created property.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The thing is that the export had to be done at the top level level so not inside the `Image` component but outside it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, you can/should always only access properties of the root node of a component.